# Add another variable to array to use it in foreach-loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I have a function in my database class, which gives me a list of events a certain user is attending

```
function getEventList($uid)
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $eventSQL = "SELECT em.eventID, e.eventName, e.eventTime FROM eventmembers em INNER JOIN events e ON em.eventID = e.eventID WHERE userIDInvited = :uid";
    $eventPrepare = $this->prepare($eventSQL);
    $eventPrepare->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
    $eventPrepare->execute();
    return ($eventPrepare->rowCount() > 0)
        ? $eventPrepare->fetchAll() : array();
}
```

To access these results I'm simply doing this

```
//php

$eventList = $db->getEventList($userid);
if($eventList == NULL){
$smarty->assign('events', 'No events'); 
}
else{
$count = sizeof($eventList);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $smarty->assign('events', $eventList);
}   
}

html

<p>MY EVENTS</p>
    {foreach from=$events item=result}
        <a href="https://localhost/FinalYear/events/{$result.eventID}.php">{$result.eventName}</a><br>
        {$result.eventTime}<br>({$result.timeRemain} Days remaining)
        <br>
        <br>
{/foreach}
```

What I want to do now is to add, that there is also saying how many days are remaining till this event occurs.

What I did was simply adding this in the for-loop.

```
$startTimeStamp = strtotime($date);
   $endTimeStapm = strtotime($eventList[$i]['eventTime']);
   $timeDiff = abs($endTimeStapm - $startTimeStamp);
   $numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;
   $numberDays = intval($numberDays);
```

The problem now was, then when, the user attends more than one event, the `$numberDays` will be always overwritten. So I tried to add `$numberDays` to the end of the current array index. But this gives me just an endless-loop. Without `$numberDays` `var_dump` gives me this output, when I have to entries

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["eventID"]=> string(1) "1" ["eventName"]=> string(7) "Konzert" ["eventTime"]=> string(19) "2013-03-28 00:00:00" } [1]=> array(3) { ["eventID"]=> string(1) "2" ["eventName"]=> string(4) "Oper" ["eventTime"]=> string(19) "2013-03-30 00:00:00" } } array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["eventID"]=> string(1) "1" ["eventName"]=> string(7) "Konzert" ["eventTime"]=> string(19) "2013-03-28 00:00:00" } [1]=> array(3) { ["eventID"]=> string(1) "2" ["eventName"]=> string(4) "Oper" ["eventTime"]=> string(19) "2013-03-30 00:00:00" } }
```

But I also want at the end of every entry the days remaining. The problem is, that I can't do it in another loop, because that would mean that I would need to make another loop in the .html-file inside the other loop. So it would be run through before the other loop has jumped to its next entry.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

My database-table looks like this

table `events`

```
eventID, eventName, eventDescription, eventLocaion, eventTime, eventHost, privacy Settings
```

table `eventmembers`

```
eventID, userIDInvited, InvitationStatus
```

Comment: You are assigning in a loop `$smarty->assign('events', $eventList);` each time it will override the previous one and value in events will be always the last one

Comment: Hi @PrasanthBendra - it doesn't make any difference if I write it in the for-loop or out of the for-loop. As soon as I add my time calculation it always results in an endless-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk through array with FOR not FOREACH loop.

```
$data = array(0 => array('name' => 'John', 'age' => '12'), 1 => array('name' => 'Megan', 'age' => '18'));
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data); $i++) {
// get your needed timestamp, for example
$time = time();
// add this to each sub-array end
$data[$i]['time'] = $time;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I messed it up with my $endTimeStapm = strtotime($eventList[$i]['eventTime']);

I thought it's not possible because this didn't work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A number of ways you could solve this:

Calculate the number of days remaining in the `foreach` loop, and print it out immediately; or add a separate array with number of days remaining. You could even create a class with (array) fields for each aspect of the event. As you already observed, right now you are overwriting the value...